# how can i fix rom build dependency missing error?

Tags: android, android-source, rom, android-13

THIS IS SCREEN SHOT OF THAT  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEEIv.png)

```
$(shell date -u +%M) was changed, regenerating...
[ 99% 165/166] finishing build rules ...
FAILED: 
hardware/qcom-caf/sdm845/media/mm-core/Android.mk: error: "libOmxCore (SHARED_LI
BRARIES android-arm64) missing libplatformconfig (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm64
)" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is inten
tional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
hardware/qcom-caf/sdm845/media/mm-core/Android.mk: error: "libOmxCore (SHARED_LI
BRARIES android-arm) missing libplatformconfig (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm)" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is inten
tional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
hardware/qcom-caf/sdm845/media/mm-core/Android.mk: error: "libmm-omxcore (SHARED
_LIBRARIES android-arm64) missing libplatformconfig (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-ar
m64)" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is inten
tional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
hardware/qcom-caf/sdm845/media/mm-core/Android.mk: error: "libmm-omxcore (SHARED
_LIBRARIES android-arm) missing libplatformconfig (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm)
" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is inten
tional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
hardware/qcom-caf/sdm845/media/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/Android.mk: error: "libOm
xVdec (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm64) missing libplatformconfig (SHARED_LIBRARI
ES android-arm64)" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is inten
tional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
hardware/qcom-caf/sdm845/media/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/Android.mk: error: "libOm
xVdec (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm) missing libplatformconfig (SHARED_LIBRARIES
 android-arm)" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is inten
tional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
hardware/qcom-caf/sdm845/media/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/venc/Android.mk: error: "libOm
xVenc (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm64) missing libplatformconfig (SHARED_LIBRARI
ES android-arm64)" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is inten
tional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
hardware/qcom-caf/sdm845/media/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/venc/Android.mk: error: "libOm
xVenc (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm) missing libplatformconfig (SHARED_LIBRARIES
 android-arm)" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is inten
tional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
build/make/core/main.mk:1124: error: exiting from previous errors.
14:53:06 ckati failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (01:21 (mm:ss)) ####
```

with the help of google , i try to build Rom for SDM712 But , when i am going last compile that time , i have error which is SDM 845/dependency missing error?Then i got wrong manifest repo downloaded or  comman file  are there ?

I am now learning stage of rom dev so , i have guidance and plz guide to next step of it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so libplatformconfig requires proprietary headers from Qualcomm, as per Android 10, so the best is to stop building it from source code, and add a prebuilt blob instead. Ref: https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/f48evw/exclusion_of_libplatformconfig_from_builds_is/